# Emu8086 programming

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I have been working on a program that is check for the palindromic words.

```
#make_COM#
include emu8-86.inc
org 100h
mov ax, 1000
mov ds, ax
call pthis

db "This program inputs a string and check for the palindromic words." ,0
putc 0dh
putc 0ah
begin: 
mov ax, 7000h
mov ds, ax
mov di, 0000
call pthis

db "Enter a string: ",0
mov dx, 10
call GET_STRING
mov cx, dx
putc 0dh
putc 0ah
back:
mov bl, [di]
cmp bl, 00h
jle stop
cmp bl, 41h
jl Not_A_Letter
cmp bl, 5Ah
jle Check_for_length
cmp bl, 61h
jl Not_A_Letter
cmp bl, 7Ah
jle Check_for_length

Not_A_Letter:
putc 0dh
putc 0ah
call pthis
db "You did not enter a valid string", 0

Check_for_length:
ret
```

I'm just wondering how can I check for the length of the input string.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Maybe you should consider to use proper code formatting so that your code is better readable.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I could get it working by using the interrupt 21. But the thing is that I am not allowed to use. Then i have no idea how it should be done

Comment: One of your first things to address should be grasping the difference between code and data (segments).

Comment: The answer to your question is inside the code of GET_STRING. You will find it in "emu8-86.inc".

Comment: @zx485 why? This is DOS 
".com" model, so everything is in single segment, with code starting at `cs:0x0100`. This is different sport (compared to regular x86 executable under any other OS).

Comment: "answer": get documentation for "emu8-86.inc" and the `GET_STRING` code, how it returns the result. It should either return at least the length of string, or the string should have some structure, like terminated by zero or '$'. It may even do both.

Comment: @Ped7g: Maybe you're right and the `pthis` function does use a NULL terminated string that is placed after its call. It would be a strange calling convention, but possible. The given code does not exclude that possibility.

Comment: @zx485 indeed it is, I was confused by the source at first too. So I googled for "documentation emu8-86.inc GET_STRING" and clicked [first link](http://www.svu.edu.eg/specialunits/acadeet/dwnldFiles/trainMater/provis/emu86_short.pdf)... there's also `pthis` described. But I wonder how it copes with `ds != cs`, it's probably written in a way to cope with that situation too, if the OP can write "Enter a string" with `ds = 0x7000`.

Comment: @Ped7g: If it's a `.COM` file as you said, `DS` should be equal to `CS` (because of its one-segment-nature). So no problem in that regard.

Comment: @zx485 but he does change the `ds` in the code. :)

Comment: @zx485 : appears to be a broken link

Answer (score 0):

The `GET_STRING` is returning zero-terminated string at `ds:di` of max size in `dx`.

Your:

```
cmp bl, 00h
jle stop
```

will catch that one (and also any character with `0x80-0xFF` value). But maybe you would rather want to use `je` to jump only when end of string is reached?

So at the `stop:` label the `di` contains length of string (may be shortened, if 0x80-0xFF char was encountered). I don't see `stop:` label in your code.

---

BTW, why do you use `7000:0000` for string buffer? Is that segment recommended by somebody, or are you just shooting into dark, hoping to be lucky?

You have about 60+ (depends on the length of command line used) bytes ahead of `0x0100`, or you can reserve space at the end of your code. If you want keep offset `0`, I would go for the command line space:

```
mov ax,cs
add ax,(100h-32)/16
mov ds,ax   ; ds:0000 points 32 bytes ahead of first instruction of code.
```

Or actually if you want to be hardcore, you can do `add ax,16` at that point of code, to overwrite beginning of your code (as it was already executed and the string `"This program inputs ..."` provides heavy reserve of bytes for overwrite). :)

(but make sure you understand what I suggest to you, so you can explain why if anyone asks).